# J2ME MulticastSocket alternative

Tags: java, sockets, java-me, multicastsocket

I have an app in Android that use communication by MulticastSocket. I want to write similar app in J2ME with communication Android <-> J2ME through WiFi using MulticastSocket. The problem is that in J2ME not exitsts MulticastSocket. There is only DatagramSocket. Can I manage with this problem using DatagramSocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. You cannot join a multicast group with a DatagramSocket. Ergo you can send to a multicast group, but not receive from one.